# Create custom list view in windows form with c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer, windowsformsintegration

I am facing issues in creating a custom list view in windows forms with c#. In the listview I want one cell as text box and 3 cell as drop down box or combo box and another one cell as image button. Actually I tried to make gridview and taking cell as combobox but i am not able to bind data to the specific combobox from database. I tried creating cell from the coding like making false to auto generate column but still i was not able to bind data to combobox in grid view.

My Code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection db = new    
         SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ram"].ConnectionString);
    db.Open();
    // String query = @"Select ItemCode from Item";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select ItemCode from Item", db);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    //cmb.HeaderText = "";
    cmb.Name = "ItemCode";
    //cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
    cmb.Items.Add("");
    //cmb.Items.Add("False");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);
 }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You shuold consider visiting http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section, please post your analysis and relevant codes as well... Otherwise this seems a low quality post.

Comment: @Aditya please see i have edited and written some code please let me know how i can do further

Comment: @user2571770 Just make sure that the DgvComboBoxCell has the item that you are trying to bind with. For example, if the DgvCmbCell has items such as 1, 2, 3 and you are trying to bind a value that is 10, then you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn that you are adding does not have any items in it.
Try binding some value that presents in the combobox items.